# Comparing the fits of 2 continuous variables

Tags: statistical-significance

I have a data set with continuous x and y values that appear to be related in a exponential way. I then have different treatment groups , which appear to shift the x and y relationships. I would like to quantify if there are indeed shifts in the exponential relationships after treatment. Therefore i was wondering what are the best and most reliable statistical tests to carry out? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a simple regression analysis. If the $y-x$ relationship follows an exponential form, then a log transform of the outcome will yield data which are related linearly. You may regress the log of $y$ onto $x$ adjusting for treatment assignment as a categorical variable. If treatment assignment is found to be statistically significant, we say that "$y$ differed $\exp(\beta_{treat})$-fold comparing groups in the treatment arm and control having the same value of $x$".

Depending on the nature of the data, a GLM is likely to model these data in a more "scientific" way, esp if the "y" variable is a rate, count, or proportion. For instance, a Poisson GLM would compare the *relative rate* of $Y$ (a count variable) between treatment and control having the same value of $x$. This line of reasoning (conditioning on the other adjustment variables) is the main rationale for multivariate regression models. (When I say multivariate I mean more than 1 regressor or covariate in the model).

Comment: Thanks for your answer AdamO. The main problem i have is that im not 100% sure if they are exponential fits or not, and in fact some of the treatments appears not just to shift the fit but to 'linearise' it. I have previously been informed that i can carry out a comparison of the best-fit values of the Y0 and k between the two fits using the extra sum of squares test- Is this also valid? Thanks again

Comment: @Dan well this is the complex part about measuring associations. You need not assume much about the nature of the relationship to produce meaningful summaries of the data you have collected. Most statisticians agree that slightly curvilinear relationships can still be meaningfully summarized with linear regression. That means that the decided factor should be your hypothesis. If you are interested in measuring a "geometric mean difference" in y for a unit change in x, then a log transform of y is justified regardless of the shape of that relationship.